# Hide Row if groupname included fixed Text angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a table which show all names from json. But Some name should be hidden, if they include groupnam4.
For example:
How can I hide row "name2" in HTML, if group.name = groupname4.

My Json looks like:

```
{
   name: "name1"
   groups:
         [
           { id: "1",
             name: "groupname1"},
           { id: "2",
             name: "groupname2"},
         ]
 },

{
    name: "name2"
    groups:
        [
         { id: "1",
           name: "groupname1"},
         { id: "2",
           name: "groupname4"},
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of groups">
  <td *ngIf="item.name != 'groupname4' ">{{ item.name }}</td>
</tr>
```

write an ngIf condition and render when the name **groupname4**